# Partitioning a hard drive, Linux / windows dual boot

Tags: linux, partition, windows

[image]

The image describes the current HD on my laptop. Its a dual booting system with Linux Mint - primary OS, and a backup Windows 7 (rarely used, but required.)

While creating the ext4 partition I made a mistake and allotted only 12GB. This is now becoming a bottleneck, I have to frequently move many installation folders and symlink to the ntfs partition.

I want to increase the 12GB ext4 to maybe 20GB --- meaning the /dev/sda2 (ntfs) will reduce in size and ext4 will increase in size.

What's the safest way to do it without screwing up the existing installation?

Comment: I don't think there's a safer way. Moving/shrinking/expand partitions is always a risky business. Backup your data, and if you can, clone the disk to an external drive, so if any problem accurs you can clone back.

Comment: Suggest you shrink `/dev/sda2` and expand `/dev/sda3` after cloning your disk and use an application such as R-Studio Disk Manager.

Comment: Windows NTFS needs 30% free to work well. At 10% you have so little working room a defrag can take forever even for smaller drive. You are at 20% free, or time to do major housecleaning or new larger drive. Also Windows 7 is EOL - end of life in Jan 2020, so time to move on from Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you to all commentators. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

1. from Win7 itself, unfragment and then shrink the disk. (diskmgmt.msc)
2. download clonezilla and boot on it (USB or CD) to save the exuisting ext4 partition
3. download a live CD of Mint and boot on it to use gparted to move/resize your partitions